# goでWin 64/32ビット、両方のバイナリをビルドできるようにするには

Tags: windows, go

go 1.4 の Windows amd64 (64ビット) 版を使って、
64ビットと32ビット両方のバイナリをビルドできるようにする方法を教えてください。

## 背景

上記を実現しようと考え、
以下のように実行しました。

```
> cd %GOROOT%/src
> SET GOOS=windows
> SET GOARCH=386
> make.bat
```

すると、32bitのバイナリしか作れなくなってしまいました。
正確には何も指定しないデフォルトの状態では32bitのバイナリができて、
`GOARCH=amd64` を設定して `go build` すると、
以下のような 6g が見つからないというエラーが発生しました。

```
> SET GOARCH=amd64
> go build
go tool: no such tool "6g"
```

なにか根本的な勘違いというか、手順が抜けているような気がするのですが、
現時点では実現方法がわかりません。

## 備考

使用している go 1.4 は http://golang.org/dl/ にある [go1.4.windows-amd64.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.windows-amd64.zip) です。
zipファイルを任意の場所に展開後に、`GOROOT` を正しく設定した状態です。
もちろん `GOPATH` は単一のディレクトリを指定済みで、
`PATH` には `%GOROOT%\bin` と `%GOPATH%\bin` を通してあります。

Comment: GOARCH=386 で make.bat したあとに GOARCH=amd64 で make.bat (2回)したところ、とりあえず両方作れるようにはなったが…これで良いのだろうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make.bash` や `make.bat` を実行する際は、pkg 内が消されます。`--no-clean` オプションを付けて両アーキテクチャで実行して下さい。`%GOROOT%/pkg/windows_XXX` が2つ出来ていれば成功です。

Comment: 両アーキテクチャですけど実行しなきゃいけない理由は何ですか? 直感的には--no-cleanで386だけやれば良さそうに思えてしまうのです。

Comment: 386 と amd64 はバイナリが異なるので、それぞれのコアパッケージは必要です。既にどちらかのアーキテクチャのコアパッケージがビルド済みなのであれば、片方だけで構いません。

Comment: golang.orgからDLできるamd64のZIPには、ビルド済みamd64用のコアパッケージが含まれているという認識だったのですが、コレは正しいですか? 仮に正しければ386だけ--no-cleanでビルドすれば良かった、ということになりそうですが…あとで試してみます。

Comment: ダウンロード配布物にはコアパッケージのビルド済みバイナリのパッケージが含まれています。

Comment: インストールされているgccが32bitだと、make.batするときにGOHOSTARCH=386になって、amd64をDLして使ってても386に差し替わるってことみたいです。あとでまとめ記事でも書きます。